# Hibernate xml set mapping problems

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I just learn Hibernate, and have some problems with xml mapping.Error code:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
```

Part of database which i want to map looks like this
[part of db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjjdv.png)

In java application i have two entity class, for each of this tables. I donot insert getters setter and constructor here for better readability.

```
 public class OccupiedBedsEntity {
    private int id;
    private Timestamp since;
    private Timestamp to;
    private int id_room;
}




  public class RoomEntity {
        private int id;
        private int roomNumber;
        private Integer numberOfBeds;
        private int id_department;
        private int idResponsibleDoctor;
        private Set beds;
    }
```

Xml mapping looks like this.

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-mapping default-cascade="all">
        <class name="entity.RoomEntity" table="room" schema="" catalog="medicine">
            <id name="id">
                <column name="id" sql-type="int unsigned" not-null="true"/>
                <generator class="native"/>
            </id>
            <property name="roomNumber">
                <column name="room_number" sql-type="int unsigned" not-null="true"/>
            </property>
            <property name="numberOfBeds">
                <column name="number_of_beds" sql-type="int unsigned"/>
            </property>
            <property name="idResponsibleDoctor">
                <column name="id_responsible_doctor" sql-type="int unsigned" not-null="true"/>
            </property>
            <property name="id_department">
                <column name="id_department" sql-type="int unsigned" not-null="true"/>
            </property>       
            <set name="beds">
                <key column="id_room"></key>
                <one-to-many class="entity.OccupiedBedsEntity"/>
            </set>
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" enter code here"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping default-cascade="all">
<class name="entity.OccupiedBedsEntity" table="occupied_beds" schema="medicine" catalog="medicine">
    <id name="id">
        <column name="id" sql-type="int unsigned" not-null="true"/>
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="since">
        <column name="since_" sql-type="datetime" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="to">
        <column name="to_" sql-type="datetime" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="id_room">
        <column name="id_room" sql-type="int unsigned" not-null="true"></column>
    </property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Maybe i have to change something not in xml, but in java classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was in this line in occupiesBebsEntity xml mapper.

```
<class name="entity.OccupiedBedsEntity" table="occupied_beds" schema="medicine" catalog="medicine">
```

Code should looks like this.

```
<class name="entity.OccupiedBedsEntity" table="occupied_beds" schema="" catalog="medicine">
```